# Find function to minimise another function

Tags: calculus, optimization, fourier-analysis

I have a function $f$ which varies with $x$, and although I know its value at $x=0$ and another point $x_1 \ (x_1>0)$, I don't know its shape or value at other points in between. However I know that it will be continuous and differentiable, so as well as $f(x)$ there will be finite values of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$.

I also have another function $g$ which also varies with $x$. Unlike $f(x)$ the equation for $g(x)$ is known; however it is a function of $f(x)$ plus various derivatives and integrals of $f(x)$, specifically:

$$g(x) = ax + bf'(x) + c\int_{0}^{x}f(x)\,dx + k(f(x)f'(x)) + l\int_{0}^{x}(f'(x))^2\,dx,$$

where $a,b,c,k,l$ are constants.

My question is, when $x=x_1$, is there a way to find the formulation of $f(x)$ which will minimize $g(x_1)$, given the infinite set of possible forms $f(x)$ might take while still satisfying the known values at $x=0$ and $x=x_1$?

I have a hunch the answer may lie in the frequency domain, i.e. perform some kind of transformation on $g(x)$ which reveals what Fourier components $f(x)$ would need to be made up of in order to give the smallest possible value of $g(x_1)$. I can attack this problem with brute force (using a computer to search for the Fourier components of $f(x)$) but an analytical solution (frequency domain or otherwise) would be welcome.